# Big-O Landau equation for a complex number

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $u=y+iz$ be a complex number.

For the Big-O Landau symbol, do we have that
$$
O(\lvert u\rvert^4)=O(y^4+z^4)?
$$

I am not sure. Anyhow it is $\lvert u\rvert^4=y^4+2y^2z^2+z^4$.

So I think we only have
$O(y^4+z^4)\subset O(\lvert u\rvert^4)$.

Comment: As the answer below (to which you still did not react) shows unequivocally, $$O(|u|^4)=O(y^4+z^4).$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: If $a,b$ are real, then $2ab\le a^2 + b^2.$